# Plotting a dispersion curve with complex wavevectors

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I want to reproduce a dispersion curve from P. Zou's thesis found here: http://www.ipd.anl.gov/anlpubs/2001/06/39620.pdf on Pg. 31, Eq. 2.13.
The problem is, the code below only gives values for the real part (vp>c) of the wavevectors k1,k2 shown below; however I am also interested in the vp

```
Clear[vp, \[Omega]]
a = 2.96*^-3;
b = 4.53*^-3;
\[Epsilon]0 = 8.8541878*^-12;
\[Epsilon]r = 20;
clight = 299792458;
k1[\[Omega]_, vp_] = \[Omega]*Sqrt[1/clight^2 - 1/vp^2];
k2[\[Omega]_, vp_] = \[Omega]*Sqrt[\[Epsilon]r/clight^2 - 1/vp^2];
BJ1[n_, r_, \[Omega]_, vp_] = BesselJ[n, k1[\[Omega], vp]*r];
BY1[n_, r_, \[Omega]_, vp_] = BesselY[n, k1[\[Omega], vp]*r];
BJ2[n_, r_, \[Omega]_, vp_] = BesselJ[n, k2[\[Omega], vp]*r];
BY2[n_, r_, \[Omega]_, vp_] = BesselY[n, k2[\[Omega], vp]*r];
F[n_, r_, \[Omega]_, vp_] = BesselJ[n, k2[\[Omega], vp]*r] -BesselJ[n, k2[\[Omega], vp]*b]*BesselY[n, k2[\[Omega], vp]*r]/BesselY[n,k2[\[Omega], vp]*b];
FP[n_, r_, \[Omega]_, vp_] = Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][BJ2][n, r, \[Omega], vp] -BesselJ[n, k2[\[Omega], vp]*b]/BesselY[n, k2[\[Omega], vp]*b]*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][BY2][n, r, \[Omega], vp];
disp = Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][BJ1][0, a, \[Omega],vp]/(k1[\[Omega], vp]*a*BesselJ[0, k1[\[Omega], vp]*a]) == \[Epsilon]r*FP[0, a, \[Omega], vp]/(k2[\[Omega], vp]*a*F[0, a, \[Omega], vp]);
ContourPlot[disp // Evaluate, {vp, 0.3 clight, 2.0 clight}, {\[Omega],2 Pi*9*^9, 2 Pi*15*^9}, FrameLabel -> {"vp", "\[Omega]"},MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 5, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: I thought Jens left a comment saying this seems to have been intended as an edit of the other question, but it seems to have disappeared.  If your intentions were different, feel free to message me @MichaelE2.

Comment: Okay sorry, my intention was to clean up the question and re-post it in effort to increase visibility.  I've reedited my original question.